# EF4 Code First database generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design, entity-framework-4

I am a total beginner to Entity Framework and I am stuck where its not possible for me to make the code generate the database.

My context is like:

```
 public class ChatContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChatContext()
            : base("ChatContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatRoom>()
                         .Map(c => c.ToTable("chat_rooms"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatUser>()
                        .HasMany(u => u.Rooms)
                        .WithMany(r => r.Users)
                        .Map(c => c.ToTable("chat_users"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatUser>()
                       .HasMany(u => u.ConnectedUsers);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<ChatUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChatRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; }    
    }
```

And my Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ChatContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ChatContext>());

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

And my connection string in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ChatContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ChatContext;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Can anyone spot where the problem lies? When I build the project, no errors are returned. A break point in Global.axax shows it hits the Application_Start().

Comment: did you check in your local instance of sQL server to see whether the db is created ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Not even the database is being created.

Comment: Do I need to do an actual call/modify of one of the table to initialize the db creation?

Comment: Think so, yes, try a simple call...

Comment: Yes, you need to actually run some code that initializes the DbContext and runs a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a query. This will check if the database exists, if it doesn't then it will be created.

Comment: Exactly; nothing is done until you try to do something. A simple query of any sort will cause initialization.

Comment: When I do this I get: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.chat_rooms' - any guess?

Comment: Could you connect to the database and check what tables exists?

Comment: No tables has been created. If I did not place a null in: Database.SetInitializer<ChatContext>(null) i would get this error: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Comment: Does the database already exists? If so try to delete it and replace `Database.SetInitializer<ChatContext>()` with `Database.SetInitializer<ChatContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ChatContext>())` as in the original question.

Comment: The db does not exists and with the dropcreate... I get the error in my previous comment, arrh. I must do something wrong. :/

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, it works for me and everything I can find about the error, seems to indicate that the database itself exists, and doesn't contain model information, but if the database doesn't exists, I really don't know. Maybe you could try to change the connection string to use a different Initial Catalog, just for testing purpose.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10260/discussion-between-meep-and-xharze)